# Objective C addSubview elements are not clickable

Tags: objective-c, addsubview

I Have a horizontal `UIScrollView`. I want to do a magazine app. 
I create a dynamic `UIview` as this:

```
UIView *one=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*4, 0, 0, 0)];
```

and my view:

```
pageOneViewController *pageOne=[[pageOneViewController alloc]init];
```

and then:

```
[one addSubview:pageOne.view];
[self.scroll addSubview:one];
```

with these codes, the elements that in `pageOneViewController`, can not clickable.

if I add "pageOneViewController.view" directly to the self.scroll they can.

how can I make clickable with first situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in your code

```
  UIView *one=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*4, 0, 0, 0)];
```

Here width and height are 0, try to set background color and non zero values for height and width for view and check your view in scrollView.

```
  pageOneViewController *pageOne=[[pageOneViewController alloc]init];

  // Y value as per your need, I have set 0.
  UIView *one=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*4, 0, pageOne.view.frame.size.width, pageOne.view.frame.size.height)];
  [one addSubview:pageOne.view];
  [self.scroll addSubview:one];
```

Comment: it doesn't workf for me, but I mixed my foundation with your code, and it works! I wrote it under.  

  pageOne=[[pageOneViewController alloc]init];

    pageOne.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, pageOne.view.frame.size.width, pageOne.view.frame.size.height) ;

    
    
    [self.scroll addSubview:pageOne.view];

Answer (score 0):

You can't add root view from view controller to other views.
Use [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html) for creating viewcontrollers as pages.